# The method length() is undefined for the type

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the `length()` method to print out the length of a `String` but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. I am new to Java and I thought that this method was build into the IDE (Eclipse).

```
import class JumbleHelper {

    String word;

    public JumbleHelper(String jumbleWord)
    {
        word = jumbleWord;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JumbleHelper str1 = new JumbleHelper("maybe");
        System.out.println(str1.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: length is a method on the String class and for arrays, but not your `JumbleHelper` class

Comment: @cricket_007 not lists, no.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't implemented a function called 'length' in jumblehelper. Just because the only value in it is a string doesn't mean you can use all it's functions. That's not how inheritance works.

However, str1.word.length() will work.

Alternatively you can add a function called length in jumblehelper, like this:

```
public int length(){ return word.length() };
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know that.

Answer (score 2):

If the class `JumbleHelper` has a `String` then this doesn't mean that it has its methods. `Composition` is different from `inheritance`. In fact, you can't inherit `String` because it is `final`

You probably meant

```
JumbleHelper str1 = new JumbleHelper("maybe");
System.out.println(str1.word.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of str1 is "JumbleHelper" and not string.

- If you like to really use JumbleHelper to encapsulate a String (in that case having a static main method would be extremely weird), add a length function to JumbleHelper
- Otherwise use the Length function of a String Object directly.

Answer (score 1):

because your class JumbleHelper don't provide these function you have to add it like this or call the word on the class object like described above

```
public JumbleHelper(String jumbleWord)
{
   word = jumbleWord;
} 
public int length (){
   return this.word.length();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it adding only this: import java.lang.String;

Comment: Sorry, this import makes no difference. Anyway, you do not have to import String.

Comment: This import makes difference for me, I had to import it because I did not have it. In some cases, the faults in the execution are because of secondary mistakes or details to adding, since it happened to me.